# What is the source of the verse "Sam no Varunah" on the emblem of Indian navy?

Tags: vedas, mantras, shloka, reference-request

> The invocation to Lord Varuna (The Sea God) in the Vedas was adopted by Indian Navy for its emblem, with the Motto: “Sam no Varunah”, meaning: “Be auspicious unto us Oh Varuna” Source: [Indian Navy Site](https://www.joinindiannavy.gov.in/en/about-us/maritime-heritage.html#:%7E:text=The%20invocation%20to%20Lord%20Varuna,auspicious%20unto%20us%20Oh%20Varuna%E2%80%9D.)

In which Veda can we find this? Can someone mention the verse number and write the entire verse along with the English translation?

Comment: The taittariya upanishad has a variant of it

Answer (score 1):

Most sources just say it's from the Vedas and leave it at that. In fact, it comes from the Taittiriya Upanishad.

According to this [website](https://www.pscarivukal.com/2021/05/25-confusing-facts-psc-part-2.html), as well as [this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Limca_Book_of_Records/Py9LAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=taittiriya%20upanishad%20%22sam%20no%20varunah%22&dq=taittiriya%20upanishad%20%22sam%20no%20varunah%22&printsec=frontcover),

> The motto for the Indian Navy is *Sam no Varunah* (Let the Lord of the Seas be propitious to us). Suggested by the then Governor General of India, C. Rajagopalchari, it is taken from the Taittiriya Upanishad and was adopted by the Indian navy.

The actual line from the [Taittiriya Upanishad](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79772.html) is slightly different, Rajagopalachari likely modified it a little to make it shorter and more 'motto-like.'

> Here follows the mantra which has to be recited for the removal of obstacles on the path of yoga:
>
> ॐ शं नो मित्रः शं वरुणः । शं नो भवत्वर्यमा । शं न इन्द्रो बृहस्पतिः । शं नो विष्णुरुरुक्रमः ॥ १ ॥
>
> **oṃ śaṃ no** mitraḥ **śaṃ varuṇaḥ** |
> śaṃ no bhavatvaryamā |
> śaṃ na indro bṛhaspatiḥ |
> śaṃ no viṣṇururukramaḥ || 1 ||
>
> Om. May Mitra be propitious to us, and Varuṇa propitious be; may Aryaman propitious be to us; propitious be Indra and Bṛhaspati to us; to us propitious may Viṣṇu of vast extent be.
>
> [[Shloka 1 of the Taittiriya Upanishad, Shiksha Valli]](https://shlokam.org/shamnomitrah/)

In the original line, Mitra is first invoked, which is why Varuna's name is split from the initial opening words.

Comment: what is the proof that Rajagopalachari modified it?

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay - perhaps 'modify' was the wrong word. The original line is '_om sam no mitrah sam varunah_', which means '_Mitra and Varuna be with us_,'  and Rajagopalachari removed the part about Mitra because Varuna was the only one relevant to the navy.

Comment: I got your point. But is there any solid proof that he really did that? I mean, there could be another verse in the Vedic literature which is exactly the verse I am looking for. That would make more sense.

Comment: Your link is not working.

Comment: 2nd link, to be specific.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay - very possible that it exists elsewhere, and yes, that'd make more sense. Perhaps someone else may find it.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay - I fixed the link, thanks for letting me know. The 'taittiriya upanishad' link goes to the correct chapter in the part of the upanishad that's relevant, and the last link, the one that was broken, goes to the shloka by itself.